# Any limitations or location differences between malloc and BSS?

Tags: c, allocation

*(For the sake of the question, please ignore the pros/cons of global variables.)*

Do global variables live in the same memory space as dynamically allocated memory?

For example, normally if I have a large multi-megabyte data structure I want to have available in memory, I malloc() the amount I need and use a struct pointer from there.

My question is, is there any difference in memory between that and just defining the large struct as a global? I know uninitialized globals have their size defined in the object BSS but won't actually occupy space in the object file, so in a sense they are being allocated at runtime. But is there any limit to the size of globals, as defined by BSS? Are they being allocated in a way other than malloc?

Comment: This is all going to be highly system dependent.

Comment: Global variables in the BSS segment are allocated all at once when the module is loaded. This is fine if you plan to use all or most of it throughout the program's lifetime but is potentially wasteful otherwise.

Comment: Everything is implementation-defined. I know implementation which allocates the memory from the OS pool dynamically in the startup to place static duration objects there. In this case there is no difference as the same allocation mechanism is used.

Comment: Define "memory space". A lot of these differences are just academic when it comes down to it due to how a modern kernel virtualizes everything. It's worth noting that in 2020 "large" does not mean "multi-megabyte". I'd reserve that term for something using >20% of system memory, or like 4GB+, excepting of course if you're on some constrained embedded environment. If that's the case, you're going to need to be specific about the architecture and OS you're using, if any.

Comment: @tadman Good point. I'm talking regular desktop computers (Windows/Linux). And multi-megabyte is more like multi-hundred-megabyte, but still a drop in the bucket of total available memory. I'm looking at it from the perspective of stack space, which is still microscopic.

Comment: It's not in the stack if that's what you're asking. That's exclusively for functions, which includes `main()`.

Comment: Oh I know it's separate, I was using it for size comparison, since stack is so small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64).

Static objects are not allocated with `malloc` (and of course, you must not attempt to `free` them).  Memory is allocated for them by the kernel when the binary is `exec`ed, along with the rest of your program's code and data.  This is usually called "load time" rather than "run time" since it happens before any of your program's code actually executes.  The only difference is that the memory allocated to `.bss` is not filled with data loaded from the binary.  Like the rest of the program, it is typically demand-paged, so that (zeroed) physical memory will only be allocated when the space is actually read or written, and may be swapped to disk later. It is more or less equivalent to an anonymous `mmap`.

(I use the word "static" here in the sense of storage duration, not scope, and it applies equally to global as well as `static` variables in C.  There are some differences in memory placement between the two for position-independent code, which I will not go into, but it doesn't substantially change the information below.)

I presume you know how `malloc` works in general, and how it gets memory from the OS (via either `sbrk` or anonymous `mmap`, typically the latter for large objects), so I won't describe that.

The main difference you're likely to encounter is that, with default compiler settings, static data (including bss) is limited to about 2GB.  The Linux compiler toolchain uses the ["small" code model](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models) by default; all code and static data are accessed using 32-bit signed RIP-relative displacements, and therefore any two such addresses must be within 2 GB of each other, so in fact the limit applies to the total size of all code and static data.  If you exceed this limit, your program will fail to compile or link.  (In fact, in some tests, it is possible to have one object larger than this, if you are lucky enough to have it right at the end of your data, but that's unlikely to work out in a real program.)

You can avoid this limit by selecting the "medium" or "large" code model when compiling, so that that 64-bit absolute addresses are used, but the tradeoff is that they result in larger and less efficient code, potentially for your entire program.  So unless you have very particular reasons for wanting to allocate your large objects statically, it is probably better to allocate it dynamically.

For very large allocations, if portability is not essential, you may prefer to use an anonymous `mmap` directly, instead of `malloc`.  This gives you more control over when to return the memory to the OS (with `munmap`), and also lets you take advantage of features like `mprotect`, `madvise`, huge pages, etc, for finer-grained control over the MMU and paging mechanisms.

In general, however, memory is memory, regardless of how it's acquired.

Answer (score 2):

> Do global variables live in the same memory space as dynamically allocated memory?

In most modern platforms, yes, processes see memory as a single, flat memory space (but they typically cannot access all the actual memory there is; it is a virtual space).

> I know uninitialized globals have their size defined in the object BSS but won't actually occupy space in the object file, so in a sense they are being allocated at runtime.

Everything is "allocated" at runtime, not just BSS areas. Programs do not carry allocated memory with them, but rather they use a file format that specifies how memory needs to be laid out (including contents, page flags, alignment, position, contents...), among other details.

The operating system takes that information when loading the program and creates a process that fits those needs, and then starts the program.

> But is there any limit to the size of globals, as defined by BSS?

That depends on the platform, but in most cases you won't notice the limit unless you want to request unusual sizes. See Nate's answer for a very good overview for Linux x86_64.

> Are they being allocated in a way other than malloc?

The information about BSS in the program is used by the operating system to map some memory filled with zeros, as explained above, even before the program starts running.

On the other hand, `malloc()` is a standard C library call that uses whatever facilities the operating system offers to request memory dynamically. In other words, when the program is already running.

But both end up in the same memory space as seen by the program (in most modern platforms).